# bootstrap-switch does not fire checkedchanged on asp.net checkbox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, bootstrap-switch

I'm using two asp.net ckeckboxes (chk1, and chk2) in a Web Forms project with MasterPage, and I'd like when I click over chk1, the chk2 becomes disable and viceverse without refreshing the entire page, so I'm using updatepanel to achieve this, I just implement the CheckedChanged event on the chk1 and put its AutoPostBack attribute to "true", and everything is ok.

The problem is when I try to implement the bootstrap-switch plugin (the two checkboxes seems like bootstrap-switch perfectly), but the problem is that when I click on the chk1, then the CheckedChanged is not fired, so the enable property of the chk2 is not affected.

I think the problem is when the user clicks on the chk1, in fact the click happens over the span's element's of the bootstrap-switch instead of the chk1 itself.

Please help, sorry for the english.

**Update 1:**

This is the source code of the page when it is running (right click on the browser), so you can see the bootstrap-switch libraries needed are present:

```
<html lang="es">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>
     - Mi aplicación ASP.NET
</title><script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-switch/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" /></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./Test" id="ctl01">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="h5sbkKDqDt9VeL5xnED+gV4kWiRKNFZBx2sOsl8K60EaOVXCuj7iQZJ3QAjjzsLsrj7CnOY8SUD81Mv51jUBYfWpQL0EHuQO3uPa8Yczm/eLjURJjkDTB57Iw5RJUitxpbKigIF0l4NevEGllIgA8hU3zjrDgSCrPtUA3qs7CJO+/ukopmdmKjOkgTjjWniVywgiMskpJEGPl3fzldVSaqkj8Ikbh+OElJUyureaFxNDS7bLq90ZhlVeNNZxorYyvtaj1HxMgniGxdfx0eClL+RD3ksd+mO6kkzV8mSXx+ykvf+A3Z2gcV0wjAcfpc09oxBF8vvsEtwBbJ+WbDlZLnGqn5W7GAFmmqD2l3e8AAFO6Sh0++Ivr057G/pw+FyebisB2dEOZeb2KZbNxL9/imrP/bBFcKrcyPeGiRUaXtjd7VPTXnD8Vox3T97yjv4P" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ctl01'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl01;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>



<script src="/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('Error al cargar el marco de trabajo de cliente ASP.NET Ajax.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/respond.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/bundles/WebFormsJs?v=AAyiAYwMfvmwjNSBfIMrBAqfU5exDukMVhrRuZ-PDU01" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-switch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ctl09', 'ctl01', ['tctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel1','MainContent_UpdatePanel1'], ['ctl00$MainContent$chk1','MainContent_chk1'], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>


        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">Nombre de la aplicación</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="./">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About">Acerca de</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact">Contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="Account/Register">Registrarse</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Account/Login">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
                            </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">


    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input id="MainContent_chk1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chk1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$chk1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" class="BSswitch" data-size="mini" data-on-text="Si" data-off-text="No" /><label for="MainContent_chk1">Check 1</label>
    </div>
    <div id="MainContent_UpdatePanel1">

            <input id="MainContent_chk2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$chk2" /><label for="MainContent_chk2">Check 2</label>

</div>




            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; 2016 - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="75BBA7D6" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="3l2FbHNq3NkXeXDBNuO5RZ4xOmC254tC8PhZRAdihltuEWASclMPM3jqhsB2rrjNHLrlioMYf4cBMhfvlMRCUVMkZXg6Bmvc06rKj2GCmkK97sprq9puXxVbM2rKg+DDwC9aG2lPJIcCLM1viuOkLw==" />
</div></form>
    <script>
        $("[class='BSswitch']").bootstrapSwitch();
    </script>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Internet Explorer","requestId":"41bd03d14e3342bebd4c2f830342b157"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:30137/825094549df74919a4a0dc141549d775/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

**And now this is the Test.aspx file:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestBSswitch.Test" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Check 1" OnCheckedChanged="chk1_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk2" Text="Check 2" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chk1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>



</asp:Content>
```

**And now this is the Test.aspx.cs file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestBSswitch
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chk1.InputAttributes.Add("class", "BSswitch");
            chk1.InputAttributes.Add("data-size", "mini");
            chk1.InputAttributes.Add("data-on-text", "Si");
            chk1.InputAttributes.Add("data-off-text", "No");

            chk2.InputAttributes.Add("class", "BSswitch");
            chk2.InputAttributes.Add("data-size", "mini");
            chk2.InputAttributes.Add("data-on-text", "Si");
            chk2.InputAttributes.Add("data-off-text", "No");
        }

        protected void chk1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chk1.Checked)
            {
                chk2.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                chk2.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the last file I have posted: "Test.aspx.cs", in the Page_Load event I have to add that attributes manually to the "chk1" in order to obtain the "switch" effect, because if I put that attributes ("data-size", "data-on-text", "data-off-text", and "class") in the aspx editor then it does not work at runtime, and if I delete that lines of code then the CheckedChanged works, but the style of the switch does not work.

Hope I have explain me in more detail, any question please ask me.

Comment: Please include your code so we can make sure you didn't make a typo or implement a method incorrectly.

Comment: Someone help, please :)

Comment: A little late perhaps but heres an answer usefull https://stackoverflow.com/a/57597200/10795412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to figure out a similar situation. Since bootstrap-switch prevents the CheckedChanged event from firing, I would recommend using jquery and the [switchChange](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/events.html) event provided by bootstrap-switch instead, like so:

```
$('#<%= chk1.ClientID%>').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    if (state) { //if chk1's switch is set to true
        $('#<%= chk2.ClientID%>').bootstrapSwitch('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#<%= chk2.ClientID%>').bootstrapSwitch('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello @Shwell, thank you very much for your help, that is a good solution in this case, and in fact I've use it, but what if I need to save some data in my database when the user check the checkbox, I suppose that is not possible, isn't it?

Comment: @JoseA, Are you using any sort of submit button to send the form data or is it just the checkboxes?