# ASP.NET RAZOR - How to Bind razor checkBox on custom Boostrap 4 Checkbox Switch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

How would I put the codes generated by the razor on this switch?

It would work like the ckeckbox

[Image Discription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mmm2.png)

An here is the link how its work:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/GaxR2

```
 <div class="card" style="margin:50px 0">
    <div class="card-header">Checkbox to Switch</div>

    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            Bootstrap Switch Success
            <label class="switch ">
                <input type="checkbox" class="success">
                <span class="slider"></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Razor Code

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExibirInfoPosicionamento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ExibirInfoPosicionamento, new { })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late but I had some frustration with this too, got it working like this (Bootstrap 4.3.1)

Razor on my page --

```
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.YN,"toggle", new { @id = "yn1 })
    </div>
```

Editor Template 'toggle'

```
@model System.Boolean

<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m,
    new { @class = "custom-control-input" })
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m, new { @class = "custom-control-label" })
</div>
```